# Acumatica : Trigger Save validation on another Custom Button

Tags: acumatica

Good Day!

How do you trigger the validations of a view when a custom button is clicked? For instance, I have a required field of Amount in the DAC and it has the PXDefault attribute, If I saved the record without filling it up, it naturally triggers the **"Error: 'Amount' cannot be empty"** error. Now from here, I want to replicate this behavior when another button aside from SAVE button is triggered.

How do you trigger that validation? I already tried adding the PXUIVerify attribute on the field itself, but it was already triggered during page load, I tried disabling it by adding the Attribute property CheckOnRowSelected = false, but to no avail, It still triggers the validation.

Any suggestions and answers is appreciated. Thank you so much.

**Additional Question:**

What is the proper way of validating the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validation of whether a field is empty happens in a RowPersisting event in the PXDefaultAttribute. The validation of whether there are any errors on the screen happens in a CommandPreparing event in the PXUIFieldAttribute.

Since you aren't actually saving, it's would be easier to replicate the validation instead of trying to "trigger" it. The following code snippet attempts to replicate the validation by validating each record in the cache for each view on the graph.

```
public static void Validate(PXGraph graph)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < graph.Views.Caches.Count; ++k)
    {
        PXCache cache = graph.Caches[graph.Views.Caches[k]];
        PXEntryStatus status;

        foreach (object rec in cache.Cached)
        {
            status = cache.GetStatus(rec);

            if (cache.GetStatus(rec) == PXEntryStatus.Updated || cache.GetStatus(rec) == PXEntryStatus.Inserted)
            {
                cache.Current = rec;

                foreach (PXDefaultAttribute attribute in cache.GetAttributesReadonly(rec, null).OfType<PXDefaultAttribute>())
                {
                    CheckDefaultAttribute(attribute.PersistingCheck, attribute.FieldName, rec, cache);
                }

                foreach (PXDBDefaultAttribute attribute in cache.GetAttributesReadonly(rec, null).OfType<PXDBDefaultAttribute>())
                {
                    CheckDefaultAttribute(attribute.PersistingCheck, attribute.FieldName, rec, cache);
                }

                // Verifies that there are no errors on the page.
                foreach (IPXInterfaceField field in cache.GetAttributesReadonly(rec, null).OfType<IPXInterfaceField>())
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(field.ErrorText) && (field.ErrorLevel == PXErrorLevel.Error || field.ErrorLevel == PXErrorLevel.RowError))
                    {
                        throw new PXException(field.ErrorText);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Verifies that the field has a value if the PersistingCheck is not PXPersistingCheck.Nothing
protected static void CheckDefaultAttribute(PXPersistingCheck persistingCheck, string fieldName, object row, PXCache cache)
{
    if (persistingCheck != PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)
    {
        object value = cache.GetValue(row, fieldName);

        if (value == null || (persistingCheck == PXPersistingCheck.NullOrBlank && value is string && ((string)value).Trim() == string.Empty))
        {
            throw new PXException(ErrorMessages.FieldIsEmpty, PXUIFieldAttribute.GetDisplayName(cache, fieldName));
        }
    }
}
```

As a disclaimer, this methodology will miss any validation that would happen in a custom RowPersisting event.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the RaiseFieldVerifying event. Check the ARDocumentEnq graph, a button for CreateInvoice (Enter New Invoice) calls the FieldVerifying and FieldUpdated events, triggering those. You can catch the exception, like in the INTransferEntry graph:

```
protected virtual void INRegister_TransferType_FieldUpdated(PXCache sender, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    INRegister row = (INRegister)e.Row;
    {
        object toSiteID = row.ToSiteID;
        try
        {
            sender.RaiseFieldVerifying<INRegister.toSiteID>(row, ref toSiteID);
            sender.RaiseExceptionHandling<INRegister.toSiteID>(row, toSiteID, null);
        }
        catch (PXSetPropertyException ex)
        {
            sender.RaiseExceptionHandling<INRegister.toSiteID>(row, toSiteID, new PXSetPropertyException(ex, PXErrorLevel.Error, Messages.WarehouseNotAllowed, Messages.OneStep));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello @KRichardson, Is there any dynamic way to this? I mean, Is there a way for me to trigger the validations of fields that have PXDefault Attributes? For instance, I have 10 required fields, and before saving the record I need to click a process button, now i want to raise the error of those required fields, is there a way for me to trigger that fields dynamically? without doing the RaiseExceptionHandling Method?

Comment: The Save.Press() button would trigger all of the required field verification, but you wanted to verify before saving. In the past, I wrote custom logic on processes on graphs that require validation that is not the same as entering the data, for example to "Verify" the document as a whole, and baked them right into the execution of the button.  This might be the best way to handle required values before attemp

Comment: I hope there are methods that can be called to validate the cache as a whole. but anyways, thank you for the suggestions and answer, I'll think of a way to validate graph view as a whole.